# How to center TikZ-UML?

Tags: tikz-uml

I'm using the TikZ-UML package for creating an UML class. 
When i create a single class how can I center this class?

My current code is:

```
\tikzumlset{fill class=white!20}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\umlclass[type=abstract, rectangle split parts=2]{Class<T>}{
<<abstract>> calc(T a, T b) : double\\
...
}{} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I've tried to center the class with `\umlclass[type=abstract, rectangle split parts=2, x=4]` but it didn't help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You can use a figure environment and `\centering` or (if you do no want a caption) you could use `\begin{center}...\end{center}`.

Comment: If you mean centering the diagram on the page/textblock, then this is no different from centering any other thing (text, image, table), and TeXnician's suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: Besides making a working example (as @StefanPinnow mentioned) it would also be helpful to provide an image with the current output and how you would like it to look (just edit it with a simple graphics editor like Paint or equivalents on Linux/Mac).